# PHP round() not rouding to two places as expected

Tags: php, numbers, rounding, php-7

I'm trying to round a large number I have and it seems that round is not functioning properly. The output of this should be `1.53` but I'm getting `1.5300000000000000266453525910037569701671600341796875`.

```
$roundMe = 1.5294000046599232067734419615590013563632965087890625;
$rounded = [
    'rounded' => round($roundMe)
];
```

What would cause this to not output what I expect?

Comment: The number is stored in binary, which means further rounding and rounding again when converting to decimal.

Comment: What OS are you using and what exact version of PHP? I just tried this on Windows with PHP 7.1.14 and all seemed to be working fine

Comment: PHP 7.1.6 on Mac OS.

Comment: Please add the code where you use the variable, and the OS you are using.

Comment: @DioneiMiodutzki See updated post, I'm using it within an array. It seems that setting it before the array to a variable and then using that variable in the array works but isn't optimal for me.

Comment: but how do you know the stored value? are you printing it? saving it in a database?

Comment: @DioneiMiodutzki The value comes from a simple function calculation.

Comment: What i'm asking is where you are using this array - are you printing it, saving in the database or what.. how do you know the value that is stored in the array after the round?

Comment: 1.53 does not have [a precise representation in floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Representable_numbers,_conversion_and_rounding), welcome to floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @Sammitch I'm noticing it's a pain to work with floats, is there a way to still have decimals but not floating point?

Comment: Use an integer and pretend it's a decimal, like the [`DECIMAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) type in mysql. If you're dealing in units of currency you MUST do this, and there are [libraries for it](https://packagist.org/packages/moneyphp/money).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[round()](http://php.net/round) returns a `float` rather than `string` so you have to deal with floating point arithmetic and its quirks:

> ```
> float round ( float $val [, int $precision = 0 [, int $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ]] )
> ```

Depending on your exact needs, you may want to give [number_format()](http://php.net/number_format) a try:

> ```
> string number_format ( float $number [, int $decimals = 0 ] )
> ```

… or just live with it (it shouldn't be an issue in most use cases).

---

P.S. Here's a [test case](https://3v4l.org/64uMe) that actually reproduces the issue:

```
ini_set('precision', 17);
var_dump(round(1.53, 2));
ini_set('precision', 50);
var_dump(round(1.53, 2));
```

Comment: That would make sense. I'm using the output value to search a database where it matches so I'll just have to convert it to a string.

Comment: In this case, it would make sense to round it on the database itself.