# Accessor overrides custom validation rule

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, accessor

I have created a custom rule to make sure the number is of two decimal places. The database has numbers stored as `decimal(19,4)`. To display the number with only two decimal places, I also have put an accessor in place. Now the problem is that the accessor overrides the custom validation rule.

the relevant part from custom validation rule

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $precision = Config::get('accounting.decimal');
    return preg_match('/^\d+(\.\d{1,'.$precision.'})?$/',$value);
}
```

the accessor in model

```
public function getRateAttribute($value)
{
    $precision = Config::get('accounting.decimal');
    return round($value, $precision);
}
```

the validation rule in the livewire component

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'editing.rate' => ['required', new NumberFormat()],
        ];
    }
```

Desired behavior:
Whenever a user enters a number with more than two decimal places, it should throw the customer validation error.
Every time the field is used anywhere else to display, it should show the number with two decimal places. For eg: 78.9800 should be displayed as 78.98.

any ideas why this is not happening?

Edit:

Did a little more testing and this seems to be a laravel livewire issue. I am binding data directly to the model property. Because of that, when I edit the field, the accessor is immediately called before validation occurs.

Workaround:

I canceled the data binding to the model property. This solved the issue.

Still is there a better way to use laravel-livewire data binding to model property and use an accssor that would not override the validation rule.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP round() not rouding to two places as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49759648/php-round-not-rouding-to-two-places-as-expected). Kindly read what is an integer, how it is stored and what you actually want. This is a basic programming concept you ought to grasp.

Comment: no, it does not. My issue is the accessor overriding the custom validation rule. If I remove the accessor, the rule works fine.

Comment: Can you show how your validation is being called? It seems that you don't validate reuqest data, but object data here?

Comment: $this->validate();
Livewire way of validating.
I was doing editing.rate (editing being model property). When I changed to rate directly and later assign it to model (editing.rate) after validation, it seems to work.